# To use or not to use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<img id="mypic">` that i need to change with an interval its src.

Should I use jQuery or not?
Should I do:

- `document.getElementById('mypic').src='src2';`

or

- `jQuery('#mypic').attr('src','src2');`

Comment: Are you using jQuery *elsewhere*? In *either* case, the vanilla JavaScript approach here is fine...and faster.

Comment: Since you're just accessing an id, plain old JavaScript will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It...doesn't really matter. I'd say use jQuery if you are using it in other places in your code, otherwise..it is up to you. However, if you are doing this in an interval, it would be slightly (but not noticeably) faster to use natural JS.

Comment: I'd also like to add that it's not worth to bring in jQuery (or any other JS framework) just to do this single task.

Comment: @yes123 if your doing any substantial amount of DOM manipulation use jQuery for ease of development. If you _NOTICE_ a bottle neck then optimise it to use the DOM directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery if the benefit of having convenient selectors and AJAX support is worth the 29 KB it'll add to your page download time. For most of my uses, it is worth is.

Also, for your JQuery code snippet, the $ character is the JQuery selector. So, you can do this:

```
$('#mypic').attr('src','src2');
```

In my opinion, JQuery is very concise, and you can get a lot done once you get used to it.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use jQuery when you're selecting an id. `document.getElementById` is lightning quick.

Comment: Matt, if you're using JQuery elsewhere on the site, then it's usually best not to mix raw DOM traversal with JQuery selectors. I use JQuery to select IDs for consistency's sake. I think they're both valid approaches, and it really boils down to personal preference.

Answer (score -2):

You should not use jQuery if you don't know how to do it in plain Javascript.
Looks like you know, feel free to use it :)

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question + I demostrated I can do it without jquery